# How to create Mongoose One-To-Many relationship entities in a single payload?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nosql

I have 3 Mongoose models: Country, State and City.
Following is the schemas for all three

**Country.model.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable id-blacklist */
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { ICountry } from '@swyft/interfaces';
interface ICountryWithDoc extends ICountry, Document {}
const CountrySchema: Schema<ICountryWithDoc> = new Schema<ICountryWithDoc>(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        states: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'State' }],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const Country = mongoose.model<ICountryWithDoc>('Country', CountrySchema);
export { Country };
```

**State.model.ts**

```
    /* eslint-disable id-blacklist */
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { IState } from '@swyft/interfaces';
interface IStateWithDoc extends IState, Document {}
const StateSchema: Schema<IStateWithDoc> = new Schema<IStateWithDoc>(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },

        country: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Country',
        },
        cities: [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'City',
            },
        ],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const State = mongoose.model<IStateWithDoc>('State', StateSchema);
export { State };
```

I'm trying to create country and its states in a single payload. But throws an error

```
**{
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Country validation failed: states.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value \"[{\"name\":\"Punjab\"},{\"name\":\"ICT\"}]\" at path \"states.0\"",
    "code": 500
}**
```

This is the payload im trying to create on POST /api/country endpoint

```
{
   "name":"Pakistan",
   "states":[
      {
         "name":"Punjab"
      },
      {
         "name":"ICT"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can i achieve the relationships created in a single go.

Comment: You have `country` in your state, but you don't have that in your json, objectId cannot be null

Comment: I removed the country in my state model. The error still persists

Comment: Does that error say country or city now?